# npm run build error NG8001, NG8002, NG8003 during build docker image

Tags: angular, docker, npm

There are several errors during dockerizing my Angular project.

The point is that there is no error when I run `ng serve` or `npm run build` command.
I set `"strict": false,` in tsconfig.json file as well.

I used this command to the dockerize angular project:

```
docker build -t myProject:latest .
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
#stage 1
FROM node:16.15.0 as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

#stage 2
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=node /app/dist/myProject /usr/share/nginx/html
```

I can say there is an error in every single component and module in my project, for example:

```
error NG8001: 'mat-paginator' is not a known element:
error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but itself has errors
error NG8003: No directive found with exportAs 'ngForm'.
error NG8002: Can't bind to 'pageSizeOptions' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-paginator'.
error NG8002: Can't bind to 'length' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-paginator'.
error NG8002: Can't bind to 'label' since it isn't a known property of 'app-text-input'.
```

Here is the latest output before the error comes up:

[image]

All Versioning:

```
Angular CLI: 13.3.7
Node: 16.15.0
Package Manager: npm 8.5.5
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 13.3.10
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1303.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular   13.3.7
@angular-devkit/core            13.3.7
@angular-devkit/schematics      13.3.7
@angular/cdk                    12.2.13
@angular/cli                    13.3.7
@angular/material               12.2.13
@schematics/angular             12.2.17
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.6.4
```